# How do I run Facade on Windows 7?

Tags: technical-issues, facade

Facade is a drama game, where the player can walk around and talk to NPCs.

I've been trying to get it running on my Windows 7 PC, but it keeps saying that it need more CPU. It also said to restart my computer or turn off all of my applications. I've been trying to do that several times, but it still doesn't run.

I've looked on the help page on Facade, but it just says to do something I already did.. Any help?

My PC:

Aspire V3; Intel Core i7-4702MQ 2.2 GHz with Turbo Boost up to 3.2GHz; NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M; 17.3 HD+ Acer CineCrystal LED LCD; 6GB RAM; 750 GB HDD; DVD-Super Multi DL drive; Acer Nplify 802.11a/b/g/n + BT 4.0; 6-cell Li-ion battery (If this is what you were asking for)

(FIXED) Just had to get on my old Windows XP computer. I guess Windows 7 can't take the old game.

Comment: @Ari Specs aren't an issue- the game is from 2005 and isn't designed for operating systems newer than XP. OP, how much do you know about compatibility mode?

Comment: It works for OS X 10.6.8

Comment: @Eric - you should add an answer to the question instead of editing the question itself :-)

Answer (score 2):

Facade is meant to be played in Windows XP and can't be played in newer Windows versions. But like what Studoku mentioned, you can use Compatibility Mode. Just right-click on Facade, and click, `Run in Compatibility Mode`. Facade should then run.

Comment on this answer if  any problem still occurs. Hope this helps!